# Joint distribution of degrees of Erdös Renyi random graph

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions, random-graphs

The marginal degree distribution of any particular vertex is $$Bin(n-1,p)$$ in an Erdös Renyi random graph *G(n,p)*. Denoting the degrees of the *n* vertices as *d1*,*d2*,...,*dn*, can you please let me know what the joint distribution of *d1*,*d2*,...,*dn* would be?